# I have json file fetched by a curl call. How can i extract only the part from merchAcctNbr to distance and store it in csv file using php

Tags: json, csv, curl

{
"truncatedResults":false,
"maxResults":0,
"vmsTab":false,
"merchants":[
{
"merchAcctNbr":"10153991     ",
"merch1Nm":"PGE GREEN FUELS                                   ",
"merch2Nm":"CROW CANYON 1                                     ",
"brand":"CHARGEPOINT",
"latitude":37.778,
"longitude":-121.967,
"stdAddrLn1":"3301 CROW CANYON RD",
"stdCity":"SAN RAMON",
"stdSt":"CA",
"stdPstlCd":"94583  ",
"stdPstlCd4":"1617",
"phoneNumber":"888-758-4389",
"unleadedPrice":"",
"unleadedDate":"",
"dieselPrice":"",
"dieselDate":"",
"distance":"0.05",
"posFlag":" ",

```
    "cheapestDiesel":
        false,
    "cheapestUnleaded": 
        false,
    "fuelProducts": [
        { "id":"unleaded", "display":"Unleaded", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"diesel", "display":"Diesel", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"propane", "display":"Propane", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"ethanol", "display":"Ethanol", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"methanol", "display":"Methanol", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"cng", "display":"CNG", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"aviation", "display":"Aviation", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"marine", "display":"Marine", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"otherAlternateFuels", "display":"Other Alternate Fuels", "flag":"Y" }
    ],
    
    "maintenanceServices": [
        { "id":"generalMaintenance", "display":"General Maintenance", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"oilChange", "display":"Oil Change", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"tires", "display":"Tires", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"transmission", "display":"Transmission", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"collision", "display":"Collision", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"brakes", "display":"Brakes", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"exhaust", "display":"Exhaust", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"glass", "display":"Glass", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"inspection", "display":"Inspection", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"roadsideAssistance", "display":"Roadside Assistance", "flag":"" }
        
    ],
    
    
    
    "otherServices": [
        { "id":"rentals", "display":"Rentals", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"carWash", "display":"Car Wash", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"oversizedVehicles", "display":"Oversized Vehicles", "flag":" " },
        { "id":"twentyFourHours", "display":"24 Hour Service", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"payAtPump", "display":"Pay at the Pump", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"smartCard", "display":"Smart Card", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"gsaOnly", "display":"GSA Only", "flag":"N" }
        
    ]
}
,
{
    "merchAcctNbr":"103805       ",
    "merch1Nm":"PGE GREEN FUELS                                   ",
    "merch2Nm":"SRVCC 14 15                                       ",
    "brand":"CHARGEPOINT",
    "latitude":37.778,
    "longitude":-121.967,
    "stdAddrLn1":"3301 CROW CANYON RD",
    "stdCity":"SAN RAMON",
    "stdSt":"CA",
    "stdPstlCd":"94583  ",
    "stdPstlCd4":"1617",
    "phoneNumber":"888-758-4389",
    "unleadedPrice":"",
    "unleadedDate":"",
    "dieselPrice":"",
    "dieselDate":"",
    "distance":"0.09",
    "posFlag":" ",
    
    "cheapestDiesel":
        false,
    "cheapestUnleaded": 
        false,
    "fuelProducts": [
        { "id":"unleaded", "display":"Unleaded", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"diesel", "display":"Diesel", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"propane", "display":"Propane", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"ethanol", "display":"Ethanol", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"methanol", "display":"Methanol", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"cng", "display":"CNG", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"aviation", "display":"Aviation", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"marine", "display":"Marine", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"otherAlternateFuels", "display":"Other Alternate Fuels", "flag":"" }
    ],
    
    "maintenanceServices": [
        { "id":"generalMaintenance", "display":"General Maintenance", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"oilChange", "display":"Oil Change", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"tires", "display":"Tires", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"transmission", "display":"Transmission", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"collision", "display":"Collision", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"brakes", "display":"Brakes", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"exhaust", "display":"Exhaust", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"glass", "display":"Glass", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"inspection", "display":"Inspection", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"roadsideAssistance", "display":"Roadside Assistance", "flag":"" }
        
    ],
    
    
    
    "otherServices": [
        { "id":"rentals", "display":"Rentals", "flag":"" },
        { "id":"carWash", "display":"Car Wash", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"oversizedVehicles", "display":"Oversized Vehicles", "flag":" " },
        { "id":"twentyFourHours", "display":"24 Hour Service", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"payAtPump", "display":"Pay at the Pump", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"smartCard", "display":"Smart Card", "flag":"N" },
        { "id":"gsaOnly", "display":"GSA Only", "flag":"N" }
        
    ]
}
```

}

```
`$fp = fopen("scr_fuel.json", "w");
// $fp = fopen("scr_fuel.csv", "w");

curl_setopt($apiurl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($apiurl1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS);

curl_setopt($apiurl1, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$result=curl_exec($apiurl1);
// Closing
curl_close($apiurl1);

// echo ($result);


 $jsonObj= json_decode($result, true);

//  $dataGet= explode('"merchants":', $result);
echo($jsonObj['merchants'][0]['merchAcctNbr']);`
```

Comment: i am trying scrap only from "merchAcctNbr" to "distance", and put it in a json file and convert it into a csv file, But continuously failing to scrap out the required portion